# Mouse out event doesn't move back outside the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseout

I have a button and when you hover over it, it shows some text and 2 more buttons but when I move my mouse out of it, it still stays on the hover. How do I make my code work so that it works on mouse out?
This is my Javascript:

```
var option1Button_Mouseout = function() {
    console.log('option1Button_Mouseout()');

    $('laStyle-option1-button')[0].innerHTML = outputTag;
};

var attachOption1ButtonListeners = function() {
    console.log($('laStyle-option1-button')[0]);
    $('laStyle-option1-button')[0].addEventListener('mouseover', this.option1Button_Mouseover);
    // When you mouse out of the button it brings it back to the original
    $('laStyle-option1-button')[0].addEventListener('mouseout', this.option1Button_Mouseout);
};

window.onload = function() {
    this.attachOption1ButtonListeners();
};
```

this is what it currently looks like:
https://media.giphy.com/media/9A6MoIdWBiZVFtcHyW/source.mp4

See when I hover over it it shows text and 2 buttons, when I mouse out it should go back to the picture of the hand.

Comment: Can you provide us with a JsFiddle? Then it is easier to help you.

Comment: it would be quite helpful if you included the relevent HTML of your image and button or (even better) give us a jsFiddle so we dont have to do extra work in simply giving you an answer

Comment: Thats ok. For starters use CDN images in your jsFiddle just like the image you posted for us: https://media.giphy.com/media/l4pTgiQB2e2dpuKs0/giphy.gif

Answer (score 2):

Sind it is not clear what your methods are doing, consider this example:

HTML

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <div id="myDiv1"/>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#myDiv').on("mouseover mouseenter ", function (e) {
   $("#myDiv1").show();
});
$('#myDiv').on("mouseleave mouseout", function (e) {
  $("#myDiv1").hide();
});
```

When entering the parent div the inner div will be shown. When leaving the parent div the inner div will be hidden. Also using .on as you are using jquery.

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/GR8sk/21/

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using jQuery I would use its Mouseenter and mouseleave events like so:

```
$("document").ready(function(){ 
    $(".laStyle-option1-button img").mouseenter(function(){       
        $(this).attr('src','https://media.giphy.com/media/xUOwGdPZ0chBWiQ6Ri/giphy.gif');      
    });     
    $(".laStyle-option1-button img").mouseleave(function(){       
        $(this).attr('src','https://media.giphy.com/media/l4pTgiQB2e2dpuKs0/giphy.gif');      
    }); 
});
```

Couple things to note:

- You did not add a '.' to the beginning of your jQuery reference to laStyle-option1-button (look at how the period goes before) because its a class attribute.
- You are performing unnecessary event listener loading. While this can be helpful for binding to click events, I would just use the 'bind' method to bind functions to click events:

  $( "#btnButton" ).bind( "click", myFunction);
- You need to change either the 'src' attribute of the image, or just remove the button completely and replace with another one. The former is better performing.